# What HTML does '###' add in flexdashboard/rmarkdown?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard with different sections separated by the heading ###, for example:

````
page 1
===================================== 

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### section 1

bla bla bla        

### Section 2

```{r}
# r data 
```
> Source: me!
````

I changed the CSS to include my company colors, but I wanted to add two different colors. For example: section 1 would be red and section 2 blue. 
So I created a new class and over-wrote the original `.chart-title` tag.

This works only for one and *sort-of* for the second one. I did some inspecting with Chrome and tried adding it like pure HTML in this format:

```
<div class="chart-title-2">Section 2</div>
<div class="chart-stage">
<p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
</div>
```

This appears inside the first section. I tried adding the closing `</div>` before the new section and this screws the order of the sections and columns up.

I was wondering what specifically is the '###' heading adding in HTML, so that I can replicate it to stick to a different CSS. Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't rmarkdown get translated to HTML, so that you can easily see in the browser what the exact output is? SO-markdown turns `### test` into `<h3>test</h3>`.

Answer (score 2):

The three dashes (`###`) renders as the `<h3>` tag in HTML. By using "pure" Markdown you won't be able to add any class / id to it, so I suggest directly formatting the`h3` tags by accessing explicitly the element itself, for instance:

**CSS**

```
h3 {
  color: Teal;
}

h3:first-of-type {
  color: Tomato;
}
```

I hope it helps!